# Selectors-based search through an array of elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to implement a search like `document.querySelectorAll(selectors)`, but against an array of `Node` objects, rather than the entire document?

I have a pre-selected list of `Node` objects, and I want a function that could take the same `selectors` parameter, but search inside the array.

Basically, it is a question of whether or not it is possible to do a `node.match(selectors)` check, to verify if the node matches the selector, and then I could simply iterate through my list of nodes. But I haven't been able to find if such match-check is possible.

So I want something like this:

```
function querySelectorInArray(nodeArray, selectors) {
    return nodeArray.filter(function(node) {
        return node.match(selectors); // this line is what I want, but dunno how
    });
}
```

### Afterthought

Will it be a good idea though? I'm thinking, `querySelectorAll` is parsing `selectors` only once, but I would be doing it once for each element in the array. Will it be bad for performance? Or is there a way to avoid it, like maybe to pre-parse `selectors` and pass in an known object instead?

Comment: So, eg, with container1 parent of child1 and container2 parent of child2, you want to be able to take an array of the containers, use a selector that matches each child, and come out with an array of child1 and child2?

Comment: @CertainPerformance My array of Node elements was created not based on parent-child relationship. They are all random elements extracting from the DOM from all over the place.

Comment: Yep, that was just an example, I'm trying to understand what you want

Comment: @CertainPerformance Added example that hopefully explains it better ;)

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly that, with one tweak - the method name is `node.matches` rather than `node.match` https://jsfiddle.net/951b0Lkx/

Comment: @CertainPerformance As far as I can see in the API, `node.matches(node)` doesn't take any selectors, it takes another `Node` to compare against, which isn't what I want.

Comment: It does take selectors as an argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches `Syntax ---- var result = element.matches(selectorString);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) for that:

```
function querySelectorInArray(nodeArray, selectors) {
    return nodeArray.filter(function(node) {
        return node.matches(selectors);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try - I will test the heck out of it tomorrow and get back here ;)

Comment: If you think you can add something on what I added as the `afterthought`, that would be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add every node to a `DocumentFragment` and then use `querySelector`:
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll)